# Magento, How to change product price in view page?

Tags: magento

In Magento product view page,

I need to call 3rd party API with product option to get product price,
and I need to change the product price dynamically.

How can I update the product price in view page so that I can pass right price to cart?

I tried adding this input tag in options.phtml,

```
<input type='text' name='price' value='999' />
```

and I click 'Add to cart' button, but the price is not changed in cart page.

please advise me,

Comment: you want to update the price for that product or what ..? please explain briefly ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to set custom price in this way because when magento add a products to cart it does not take price from the form post data.

In magento,there is option of setting custom price of product at run time.So you have to call a observer on checkout_cart_product_add_after event and in that observe,get the custom price from the form post data and set the product custom price in following way:

```
  $request=$observer->getRequestParam();
  $price=$request->getPrice();
  $qty=1;
  $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
  $item->setCustomPrice($price*$qty);
  $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
  // Enable super mode on the product.
  $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```